# What is the fastest method of getting first n items in the calculated list?

Tags: c++, algorithm, qt, sorting, optimization

I am  working on the following task:

For every item in `list1` find first `n` best matches for item in `list2`

Items themselves are fairly big (around 1.5 kb each), and there is a function for their comparison.

What I have been doing till now, can be expressed in following pseudocode:

```
for every item1 in list1 {
    for every item2 in list2 {
        put index of item2 in index_buffer
        put match(item1,item2) in value_buffer
    }
    sort index_buffer by value_buffer
    put first n of index from index_buffer, value_buffer(index) in result_ buffer 
}
```

I wonder, what are better/faster ways to do that.

The language I am using is c++, with Qt as a framework. I know for sure that the same task with same data is executed 4 times faster in matlab, which shouldn't be the case.

Here is relevant code: http://pastebin.com/xsWsWzgp

Comment: Are the items sortable? Then sorting first and finding using binary search alg. may be faster.

Comment: They are not sortable, sadly. Only thing i can get from them is their 'similarity score' from the match function

Comment: if a item2 can only match one item1, and assuming your match function is expensive, you could create a flag on a item2 to tell if it has already been matched to avoid calling the match function again

Comment: Does the solution implemented in MATLAB use the same algorithm?

Comment: @JoãoAugusto Your solution is more space expensive, and perhaps the probability of "saving" comparision is not high enough.

Comment: Well, as you describe it, this is a [nearest neighbor search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search) problem: since you make a lot of queries from `list1`, it makes sense to organize `list2` in advance so that each query executes faster. This is an entire research area, but if your similarity function corresponds to a metric, then several methods apply, most based on tree structures. For a concrete example, see the [vp-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vp-tree).

Comment: It is nearest neighbour search - items inside are 128-dimentional points, and the match function operates on their euclidian distance (mapping it to 1 - 0)

Comment: @Srv19 In Euclidean space there's a bunch of algorithms available. More interesting are approximate search methods, if this applies to your problem. In this case, the state of the art as I know it is [optimized product quantization](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/kahe/publications/pami13opq.pdf).

Comment: BTW, from your given algorithm, you don't need a complete sort, `std::nth_element` or `std::partial_sort` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a faster way to do your step 2. Actually, you combine it with step 1.

Right now you keep all the results, sort them, and pick the top N to put in the output buffer. What you could do instead is create a priority queue that holds N items, and just keep the top N found so far. In pseudocode, it looks something like this:

```
for every item1 in list1 
{
    create empty priority queue to hold n items
    for every item2 in list2 
    {
        value = match(item1, item2)
        if priorityqueue length < n
            add value and index to priority queue
        else if value > lowest value currently in priority queue
        {
            remove lowest value from priority queue
            add new value and index to priority queue
        }
    }
    add items from priority queue to result buffer
}
```

Look into the STL [std::priority_queue](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/).

If the number of items requested (n) is much smaller than the length of list2, that will save you a lot of time.

As somebody else pointed out, it might be reasonable to remove items from list2 (or somehow flag them) when they match, so that they won't be matched again. Unless of course you want and expect duplicate matches.

Comment: i will try this and report result.

Comment: didn't use this for my original problem, but it was very handy later. Thanks!